# Running custom exe in Cygwin(windows)

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, cygwin

Hello I installed cygwin and ssh package on a server and I connect as expected.

Then I am trying to run a exe file which isn't from Windows, it's a just custom tool that I use for Test Automation, terminal freezes when I try to run it or nothing happens.

Exe files like cmd and powershell work in Cygwin as expected.

Do I have to compile that custom exe file so that Cygwin can recognize and run it?

How do I do that ?

Comment: Indeed, you cannot run directly linux (or wsl) binary files in cygwin. Is it a tool in puiblic domain ?

Comment: No, it's not, it's in house software tool made for internal usage. How can I make it runnable for cygwin?

Comment: Can you compile in cygwin ?

Comment: I will try. But just found out that this software can't be compiled with gcc, only autoit.